# problems in my python code to clean csv files

Tags: python-3.x, csv, data-preprocessing

i'm trying to write a code that removes the first line from a csv file in a directory and subdirectories if its blank and makes the csv keys the first line it runs but does not modify the csv can someone help? its for a large dataset so it cant be done manually:

```
import csv
import os

def remove_extra_rows(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

        # Find the row containing column headers
        header_row = None
        for row in csv_reader:
            if any(cell.strip() for cell in row):
                header_row = row
                break

        # Read the remaining rows, ignoring any rows before the header row
        rows = [header_row] if header_row is not None else []
        for row in csv_reader:
            if any(cell.strip() for cell in row):
                rows.append(row)

    # Write the modified rows back to the CSV file
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerows(rows)

def process_directory(path):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith('.csv'):
                full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                remove_extra_rows(full_path)
                print(f'Processed {full_path}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    directory_path = r'path goes here'
    process_directory(directory_path)
```

This Python code defines two functions: remove_extra_rows and process_directory.

The remove_extra_rows function takes a filename as input, reads the CSV file at that location, removes any rows before the row containing the column headers, and then writes the modified rows back to the file.

The process_directory function takes a directory path as input and recursively walks through the directory tree, processing any CSV files it finds by calling the remove_extra_rows function.

The main part of the code checks if this module is being run as the main program, and if so, sets a directory path to process and calls the process_directory function on that path.

Note that this code assumes that the CSV files have a row of column headers and that any rows before that row should be removed. It also assumes that the CSV files use the default comma delimiter. If the files have a different delimiter, the csv.reader and csv.writer functions should be configured to use that delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simplify your "find blank row" logic and redefine it as, for each row:

- strip any cells in the row
- if the resulting row has some number of cells, and the row isn't equal to a single empty cell, then you've found your header, break

At that point the `row` variable will be the header (first real row of the CSV), you don't need to make a special copy of it.  You can also skip the individual row iterating and use the `list()` function to get all the remaining rows:

```py
csv_strs = [
    " \n  \nCol1,Col2\naaaa,bbbb",
    "\nCol1,Col2\ncccc,dddd",
    "Col1,Col2\neeee,ffff",
    "   \nCol1\ngggg\n\nhhhh",  # blank row in between gggg and hhhh
]

for csv_str in csv_strs:
    f = io.StringIO(csv_str)
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    rows: list[list[str]] = []

    row: list[str] = []
    for row in reader:
        row = [x.strip() for x in row]
        if row != [] and row != [""]:
            break
        else:
            print(f"skipped {row}")

    rows.append(row)
    rows.extend(list(reader))

    print(f"data {rows}")
```

```
skipped ['']
skipped ['']
data [['Col1', 'Col2'], ['aaaa', 'bbbb']]
skipped []
data [['Col1', 'Col2'], ['cccc', 'dddd']]
data [['Col1', 'Col2'], ['eeee', 'ffff']]
skipped ['']
data [['Col1'], ['gggg'], [], ['hhhh']]
```

You can get rid of `: list[list[str]]` and `: list[str]` if you don't want the type hints.